# Base image satisfies tensorflow version but docker still downloads tensorflow from requirements.txt

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile as below:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.13.2-gpu-py3
COPY src/ /

WORKDIR /Mask_RCNN
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install .
RUN pip install slidingwindow

ENTRYPOINT ["python3","/Mask_RCNN/inference_docker.py"]
```

and a requirements file like this:

```
numpy
scipy
Pillow
cython
matplotlib
tensorflow>=1.3.0
scikit-image
opencv-python
h5py
imgaug
IPython[all]
```

So pulling `tf 1.13.2` satisfies `tensorflow>=1.3.0` but when creating an image, docker tries to download the latest `tf=2.3` as indicated in `requirements.txt` . However, this behaviour breaks my code since it could only run on `tf>1.3 and tf<2`. Shall I modify the `requirements.txt` by removing `tensorflow>=1.3.0`, or are there any commands that would avoid this conflict?

Comment: _However it does breaks my code since it could only run on `tf>1.3 and tf<2`. Shall I modify the `requirements.txt` by removing `tensorflow>=1.3.0`, or are there any commands that would avoid this conflict?_ Unless I'm missing something, couldn't you just add the upper bound to the requirements.txt?

Comment: Even if I include an upper bound it still will look for latest `1.x` which is `1.15`. I want a behavior like if base image provides an item in requirements, then that item in requirements wouldn't `pip install` at all.

Comment: Can you share the exact bounds you used in the file?

Comment: @AMC Added per your request.

Comment: How did you add the restriction for version 2.* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the DockerFile on Tensorflow you can see that the Tensorflow Docker image is built on top of Ubuntu by [installing Tensorflow by pip](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/dockerfiles/cpu.Dockerfile). If you reinstall TensorFlow with a higher version like TensorFlow >=1.3. It will download the latest version ie tensorflow 2.3 for you. So either remove the tensorflow from your requirements file else it will get overridden with the latest version always.

Comment: I understand it will try to download the latest version but why? Shouldn't it simply check tf 1.13 is already preinstalled and it is bigger than 1.3 and then avoid tinkering with tensorflow at the first hand?

Comment: It's because pip resolves packages like that. You may need to downgrade, upgrade packages often, so your logic is not always easy for PyPI folks to implement. I don't know what exactly happens in backend of pip